# How separate keys and values in this JSON object, using Java?

Tags: java, json

I have JSON object like

```
{
 "projector":"no",
 "video_conference":"no",
 "polycom":"no",
 "lcd":"no",
 "digital_phone":"no",
 "speaker_phone":"no"
}
```

How do I store the keys in one array and the values in a separate array?

Comment: Everyone will definitely help you once you show what you have tried so far

Comment: Try [Google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: accept some answers also...if you are putting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
 String s = " { "projector":"no", "video_conference":"no", "polycom":"no", "lcd":"no", "digital_phone":"no", "speaker_phone":"no" }";

        JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject("projector");


        Iterator iter = menu.keys();
    String[] keyArr = new String();
    String[] valArr = new String();
    int count = 0;
        while(iter.hasNext()){
                 keyArr[count] = (String)iter.next();

             valArr[count] = menu.getString(key);
           count +=1;

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `GSON`  for converting your java object to json and vice versa.

Refer this link

**http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/**

Answer (score 1):

I like Jackson from http://codehaus.org/ for JSON parsing.

```
String text = "{ \"projector\":\"no\", \"video_conference\":\"no\", \"polycom\":\"no\", \"lcd\":\"no\", \"digital_phone\":\"no\", \"speaker_phone\":\"no\" }";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(text, Map.class);
Set<String> k = map.keySet();
Collection<Object> v = map.values();

String[] keys = k.toArray(new String[k.size()]);
String[] values = v.toArray(new String[v.size()]);
```