# abstract out the key and value in json array

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have a `json array : [{"choice":"Yes","score":"1"},{"choice":"No","score":"0"},{"choice":"Not Done","score":"0"}]` 
How can I get the key and the value of the json? I want to store into database the choice and the score value.

Comment: Did you tried anything? There are lot of JSON libraries that you can use to handle JSON

Comment: @Miss_Ann get [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292155/plain-json-string-to-hashmap/26292156#26292156) from here

Comment: Please post code that you may have tried. In order to handle JSON in java, as [Thusitha Thilina Dayaratne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2125973/thusitha-thilina-dayaratne) pointed out there a lot of JSON libraries; Most of these libraries depend on you creating a POJO class. You may want to look at GSON library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How separate keys and values in this JSON object, using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825632/how-separate-keys-and-values-in-this-json-object-using-java)

Comment: You can Refer To this for help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825632/how-separate-keys-and-values-in-this-json-object-using-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the response guys. i have use Jackson library to convert JSON to map, then it solves my problem.

```
  Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  //convert JSON string to Map
  map = mapper.readValue((String)jsonarray.get(word0), new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});

  System.out.println(map);
  System.out.println(map.get("choice"));
  System.out.println(map.get("score"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an another solution to get data from jsonArray using JSONParser

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);// the file which has json data
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

// get an array from the JSON object

JSONArray lang= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("key");

 // take the elements of the json array

        for(int i=0; i<lang.size(); i++){

            System.out.println("The " + i + " element of the array: "+lang.get(i));

        }

        Iterator i = lang.iterator();



        // take each value from the json array separately

        while (i.hasNext()) {

            JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();

            System.out.println(innerObj.get("key1") +

                     + innerObj.get("key2"));

        }
```